# MySQL ExtractValue following-sibling alternative

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath, mariadb, extract-value

I'm trying to select a node's value from XML in a table in MySQL/MariaDB

Acoording to the MySQL docs, `following-sibling` is not supported as an XPath axis in MySQL. Is there an alternative?

Docs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue

My XML structure looks something like:

```
<fields>
    <record>
        <id>10</id>
        <value>Foo</value>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>20</id>
        <value>Bar</value>
    </record>
</fields>
```

I need to find the record with ID 10, and get the text in `<value></value>`.

Valid XPath would be `/fields/record/id[text()=10]/following-sibling::value/text()` which would return `Foo`

What are my options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this simple case you do not need the `following-sibling`. Try this instead:

```
/fields/record[id[text()=10]]/value/text()
```

Using the tag `id` inside the brackets leaves your context at `record` so that the following slash descends to the corresponding sibling of `id` (having the same parent as `id`).

Comment: That's it. Makes sense! It's been a long while since I've had to flex my XPath muscles but that makes total sense. Thank you!

Actually, for reference for anyone else, the last `text()` can be omitted for MySQL Extract Value. It does that automatically so the MySQL would be something like:

`SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmlData, "/fields/record[id[text()=10]]/value") as value`

Answer (score 0):

I have this XML:

```
<List>
    <Attribute>
        <Id>Name</Id>
        <Value>JOHN</Value>
    </Attribute>
</List>
```

Below is query:

> SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xml,
>   "List/Attribute[Id[text()='NAME']]/Value")
>   FROM xx;

But getting error as Unknown column 'List/Attribute[Id[text()='COUNTRY']]/Value' in 'field list'